# DropDownList not fetching right value in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to feed value in drop down menu dynamically and fetch them thereafter. It works smooth but as soon as I add a default option, all hell break loose. Irespective of what I chose from drop down, it selects the default option defacto. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here ?

```
     <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
         <td>  
             <asp:Label ID="lblBankName"  runat="server" Text="Bank Name" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
         </td>
          <td style="align-content:center">
                 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm" ID="ddlBankName" Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBankName_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                 </asp:DropDownList>

          </td>
          <td style="padding-left:5px;">

          </td>
          <td>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    //Populate BankName for DropDown List
    MSAccessConnection dropdown = new MSAccessConnection();
    DataSet output = dropdown.PopulateDropdown("SELECT distinct([Bank]) FROM [BankDetails]");
    ddlBankName.DataTextField = output.Tables[0].Columns["Bank"].ToString();
    ddlBankName.DataValueField = output.Tables[0].Columns["Bank"].ToString();
    ddlBankName.DataSource = output.Tables[0];
    ddlBankName.DataBind();
    ddlBankName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "All"));
```

}

Comment: In the `Page_Load()` - Populate Dropdown values only in case of IsPostBack = false (i.e.) `if(!IsPostBack) {//Populate Drop Down code}`

Comment: Off topic - why `ddlBankName.DataTextField = output.Tables[0].Columns["Bank"].ToString();` when probably `ddlBankName.DataTextField = "Bank";` should be enough?

Comment: Thanks ! Changed it to just Bank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is because of not using !IsPostBack condition while binding the DropDownList on page load. Try below code and it should work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Populate BankName for DropDown List
        MSAccessConnection dropdown = new MSAccessConnection();
        DataSet output = dropdown.PopulateDropdown("SELECT distinct([Bank]) FROM [BankDetails]");
        ddlBankName.DataTextField = output.Tables[0].Columns["Bank"].ToString();
        ddlBankName.DataValueField = output.Tables[0].Columns["Bank"].ToString();
        ddlBankName.DataSource = output.Tables[0];
        ddlBankName.DataBind();
        ddlBankName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "All"));
    }
}
```